# sails.js model validation in bootstrap function

Tags: validation, model, sails.js, waterline

I have a model in [sails.js](http://sailsjs.org) and before creating a new record, I want to validate the data that I wanna insert in model.

this is my model for example :

```
module.exports = {
  attributes: {
        levelNumber : {
          type : 'string',
          defaultTo : '',
          required : true,
          unique : true
        }
  }
}
```

and this is my code that I put in bootstrap.js to run :

```
  MODELNAME.validate({
    levelNumber: 10
  }, function(err){
    if (err && err.invalidAttributes) {
      console.log(err.invalidAttributes);
    } else {
      // model is valid
      console.log('validate');
    }
});
```

it always return "validate" and never return error in validation!!!!

my questions is :
1 - how we can validate and input json for a model before creating it ?

thx

Comment: Can you explain why you're trying to do this in the bootstrap function?

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason to put application logic to bootstrap.js? The fact is sails executed it **before** the app is lifted, so it is not strange that something is not working correctly.

Comment: bootstrap is run after the ORM is initialized, at least.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply add `beforeCreate` function to your Model definition under **api/models**

your model will look like this

```
module.exports = {
  attributes: {
     .....
  },
  beforeCreate: function(values, next) {
    // Validate the values HERE!!
  }
};
```

Comment: the problem is that it not validate at all ! the function not work and not return any error about it ?!!!

Comment: I want to validate model by .validate() function of models not manyally but it not work !